# Async and Dispatcher explanation

Tags: c#, events, async-await, uwp

I have a class using the code below. Additional I'm using another class to check the availability of my network connection. This class provides an event for that, which I'm using to start and stop a timer.

If the event gets fired, I always get an error message

> The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread

```
public class ViewModel : BindableBase
{

    private DispatcherTimer timerUpdate = null;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        NetworkAvailabilty.Instance.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += OnNetworkAvailabilityChanged;

        timerUpdate = new DispatcherTimer();
        timerUpdate.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
        timerUpdate.Tick += timerUpdate_Tick;

        if (NetworkAvailabilty.Instance.IsNetworkAvailable)
        {
            timerUpdate.Start();
        }
    }

    private void timerUpdate_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        // do something 
    }

    public void OnNetworkAvailabilityChanged(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (NetworkAvailabilty.Instance.IsNetworkAvailable)
        {
             timerUpdate.Start();                
        }
        else
        {
            timerUpdate.Stop();
        }    
    }
}
```

So after some research I fixed the issue using the following code:

```
    public void OnNetworkAvailabilityChanged(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (NetworkAvailabilty.Instance.IsNetworkAvailable)
        {
            Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
            () =>
            {
                timerUpdate.Start();
            });

        }
        else
        {
            Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
            () =>
            {
                timerUpdate.Stop();
            });                
        }            
    }
```

But what's behind that issue and how doeas this part of the code prevents this error message?
Even here Visual Studio tells me that I should consider to use await in front of Windows.ApplicationModel.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But what's behind that issue

`DispatcherTimer` is created on the UI thread, and it is what is called a "thread-affine" object (just like most UI components). This means that it "binds" to its UI thread and now belongs to it.

`NetworkAvailabilty` is not a UI component, and it always raises its `NetworkAvailabilityChanged` event on a thread pool thread.

Thus, `OnNetworkAvailabilityChanged` is running on a thread pool thread, and it tries to access the `DispatcherTimer` which is bound to the UI thread. That's what causes the exception:

> The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread

It's saying that `DispatcherTimer` is marshalled for the UI thread (and thus bound to the UI thread), but your app is invoking one of it's methods from a thread pool thread.

> how doeas this part of the code prevents this error message?

`RunAsync` executes its delegate on the UI thread.

Personally, I prefer to use `SynchronizationContext` instead of `Dispatcher`/`CoreDispatcher`. If you do use the dispatcher, you should `await` the call and make `OnNetworkAvailabilityChanged` an `async void` event handler.